# How to get user id from JWT authentication Token in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, rest-api, token

I am getting the Token from api call **/V1/integration/customer/token** I want to get the user id from this jwt token. How i can get it in magento2.4.5 ?

Comment: $token->getUserContext()->getUserId())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `\Magento\JwtUserToken\Model\Reader` and then call read($token) on it.

In PHP8.1 this looks like

```
public funtion __construct(private \Magento\JwtUserToken\Model\Reader $jwtReader) {
  
}

public function test() {
    $context = $this->jwtReader->read($token);
    $userId = $context->getUserContext()->getUserId();
}
```